# How to correctly handle some html tags?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to insert the following code into my html file using JavaScript, how can I achieve that please ?

This is the code that I'm trying to insert :

```
<div id="divTP2">
  <p>Langages basés sur ECMAScript :</p>

  <ul>
    <li>JavaScript</li>
    <li>JScript</li>
    <li>ActionScript</li>
    <li>EX4</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

JavaScript :

```
var mainDiv = document.createElement('div');
mainDiv.id = 'divTP2';
alert(mainDiv);

var textNodes = [
    document.createTextNode('Langages basés sur ECMAScript :'),
    document.createTextNode('JavaScript'),
    document.createTextNode('JScript'),
    document.createTextNode('ActionScript'),
    document.createTextNode('EX4')
];
alert(mainDiv);

var paragraph = document.createElement('p');
paragraph.appendChild(textNodes[0]);
alert(paragraph);

var tabLi = [
    document.createElement('li'),
    document.createElement('li'),
    document.createElement('li'),
    document.createElement('li')
};

var uList = document.createElement('ul');

for ( var i = 0 ; i < 4 ; i++ ){
    alert(i);
    tabLi[i] = tabLi[i].appendChild(textNodes[i]);
    uList.appendChild(tabLi[i]);
    //alert(tabLi[i]);
}

mainDiv.appendChild(paragraph);
mainDiv.appendChild(uList);

document.body.appendChild(paragraph);
document.body.appendChild(uList);
```

jsFiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/Qbhqv/

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you elaborate? What exactly won't work? What is it you're trying to achieve?

Comment: oh sorry, juste a second x)

Comment: post've been edited !

Comment: I think that you should call your script when the page loads <body onload="add_div()"> and make your code in a function add_div()

Comment: You should always try to avoid writing html in javascript. Isn't there another way of doing it? What exactly is you situation and what are your need? I suggest you use a templating engine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two errors , one in this block:

```
var tabLi = [
    document.createElement('li'),
    document.createElement('li'),
    document.createElement('li'),
    document.createElement('li')
};
```

The last `}` should be a `]`

The second is in the next block:

```
for ( var i = 0 ; i < 4 ; i++ ){
    tabLi[i] = tabLi[i].appendChild(textNodes[i]);
    uList.appendChild(tabLi[i]);
}
```

You are overwriting your `li` element with `tabLi[i] = ...`, so it will only contain the text which will be appended to the `ul` without `li`

Change it to this and it will work:

```
var tabLi = [
    document.createElement('li'),
    document.createElement('li'),
    document.createElement('li'),
    document.createElement('li')
];

var uList = document.createElement('ul');

for ( var i = 0 ; i < 4 ; i++ ){
    tabLi[i].appendChild(textNodes[i+1]);
    uList.appendChild(tabLi[i]);
}
```

See it [working in jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GeraldS/Qbhqv/1/)

Answer (score 0):

you have an error in this block

```
var tabLi = [
    document.createElement('li'),
    document.createElement('li'),
    document.createElement('li'),
    document.createElement('li')
};
```

you open an aray `[]` and you close an object `{}`. Change the closing `}` with `]`.

---

Also change this block

```
for ( var i = 0 ; i < 4 ; i++ ){
    alert(i);
    tabLi[i] = tabLi[i].appendChild(textNodes[i]);
    uList.appendChild(tabLi[i]);
    //alert(tabLi[i]);
}
```

to

```
for ( var i = 0 ; i < 4 ; i++ ){
    alert(i);
    tabLi[i].appendChild(textNodes[i]);
    uList.appendChild(tabLi[i]);
}
```

---

And based on your code i think that the last two rows

```
document.body.appendChild(paragraph);
document.body.appendChild(uList);
```

should change to

```
document.body.appendChild(mainDiv);
```

---

You could have tha same result with the following code

```
var html = [
    '<p>Langages basés sur ECMAScript :</p>',
    '<ul>',
        '<li>JavaScript</li>',
        '<li>JScript</li>',
        '<li>ActionScript</li>',
        '<li>EX4</li>',
    '</ul>'
];

var mainDiv = document.createElement('div');
mainDiv.id = 'divTP2';
mainDiv.innerHTML = html.join('');

document.body.appendChild(mainDiv);
```

see [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9KyGA/)

Answer (score 0):

In my view, this is the easiest way to achieve what you're doing. No need to micromanage the creation of your child elements.

```
var mainDiv = document.createElement('div');
mainDiv.id = 'divTP2';

mainDiv.innerHTML = '<p>Langages basés sur ECMAScript :</p><ul><li>JavaScript</li><li>JScript</li><li>ActionScript</li><li>EX4</li></ul>';

document.body.appendChild(mainDiv);
```

If you're putting this in the `<head>`, you should wrap it in an `onLoad` event so that it adds the nodes after the document has loaded it's elements:

```
window.onLoad = function(){

  // the code

}
```

Or if you really want to automate the process of creating lists, make a function for it:

```
var mainDiv = document.createElement('div');
mainDiv.id = 'divTP2';

createList(
    mainDiv,
    'Langages basés sur ECMAScript :',
    ['JavaScript', 'JScript', 'ActionScript', 'EX4']
);

document.body.appendChild(mainDiv);

function createList(element, header, items){

    var headerElement = element.appendChild(document.createElement('p'));
    var listElement = element.appendChild(document.createElement('ul'));

    for(var i = 0; i < items.length; i++){

        var itemElement = document.createElement('li');

        itemElement.innerHTML = items[i];
        listElement.appendChild(itemElement);

    }

    headerElement.innerHTML = header;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

This your code modified and it does what you want:

```
var mainDiv = document.createElement('div');
mainDiv.id = 'divTP2';

var textNodes = [
    document.createTextNode('Langages basés sur ECMAScript :'),
    document.createTextNode('JavaScript'),
    document.createTextNode('JScript'),
    document.createTextNode('ActionScript'),
    document.createTextNode('EX4')
];

var paragraph = document.createElement('p');
paragraph.appendChild(textNodes[0]);

var tabLi = [
    document.createElement('li'),
    document.createElement('li'),
    document.createElement('li'),
    document.createElement('li')
];

var uList = document.createElement('ul');

for ( var i = 0 ; i < 4 ; i++ ){
    tabLi[i].appendChild(textNodes[i+1]);
    uList.appendChild(tabLi[i]);
    //alert(tabLi[i]);
}

mainDiv.appendChild(paragraph);
mainDiv.appendChild(uList);

document.body.appendChild(mainDiv);
```

Note the i+1 to shit for the testNodes, since the first one is in the

. You also have to avoid the assignment to tabLi because it gets overwritten.